# Make a sublist from list using LiSP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have difficulty creating a sublist: '(((3)2)1)' from the list '(3 2 1)'.
I don't know where to start, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a careful look at the input. You'll see that every list in the result is two elements long - except the first. Since we need to handle the first cons in one way, and all of the others another, we'll split the work between two functions, the second of which will be a loop:

```
(defun nest-left (list)
  (if (null list)
      nil
    (nest-aux <?> (cdr list))))

(defun nest-aux (acc list)
  (if (null list)
      <?>
    <?>))
```

I'll leave you to fill in the `<?>`s.